# Duplicate Quantity as new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is my table

[image]

I want it to be the following, i.e., by duplicating `Quantity` of `(shopID, productID)` `Quantity` of other difference `(shopID, productID)` as new columns, `Quantity_shopID_productID`.
[image]

Following is my code:

```
from datetime import date 
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"Date":[date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,2),date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,2),date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,2),date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,2)],
                "ShopID":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                "ProductID":[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2],
                "Quantity":[3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]})


for sid in df.ShopID.unique():
    for pid in df.ProductID.unique():
        col_name='Quantity{}_{}'.format(sid,pid)
        print(col_name)
        df1=df[(df.ShopID==sid) & (df.ProductID==pid)][['Date','Quantity']]
        df1.rename(columns={'Quantity':col_name}, inplace=True)
        display(df1)
        df=df.merge(df1, how="left",on="Date")
        df.loc[(df.ShopID==sid) & (df.ProductID==pid),col_name]=None       

print(df)
```

The problem is, it works very slow as I have over 108 different `(shopID, productID)` combinations over 3 years period. Is there anyway to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `pivot` and `merge` problem with a little extra:

```
# somehow merge only works with pandas datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# define the new column names
df['new_col'] = 'Quantity_'+df['ShopID'].astype(str) + '_' + df['ProductID'].astype(str)

# new data to merge:
pivot = df.pivot_table(index='Date', 
                        columns='new_col', 
                        values='Quantity')

# merge
new_df = df.merge(pivot, left_on='Date', right_index=True)

# mask
mask = new_df['new_col'].values[:,None] == pivot.columns.values

# adding the None the values:
new_df[pivot.columns] = new_df[pivot.columns].mask(mask)
```

Output:

```
    Date                   ShopID    ProductID    Quantity  new_col         Quantity_1_1    Quantity_1_2    Quantity_2_1    Quantity_2_2
--  -------------------  --------  -----------  ----------  ------------  --------------  --------------  --------------  --------------
 0  2019-10-01 00:00:00         1            1           3  Quantity_1_1             nan               4               5               6
 1  2019-10-02 00:00:00         1            1           3  Quantity_1_1             nan               4               5               6
 2  2019-10-01 00:00:00         1            2           4  Quantity_1_2               3             nan               5               6
 3  2019-10-02 00:00:00         1            2           4  Quantity_1_2               3             nan               5               6
 4  2019-10-01 00:00:00         2            1           5  Quantity_2_1               3               4             nan               6
 5  2019-10-02 00:00:00         2            1           5  Quantity_2_1               3               4             nan               6
 6  2019-10-01 00:00:00         2            2           6  Quantity_2_2               3               4               5             nan
 7  2019-10-02 00:00:00         2            2           6  Quantity_2_2               3               4               5             nan
```

---

Test data with similar size to your actual data:

```
# 3 years dates
dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2018-12-31', freq='D')

# 12 Shops and 9 products
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((dates, range(1,13), range(1,10)),
                                 names=('Date','ShopID', 'ProductID'))

# the test data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Quantity':np.random.randint(0,10, len(idx))},
                  index=idx).reset_index()
```

The above code tooks about 10 seconds on an i5 laptop :-)

Comment: Thanks, but if I change the dataframe to following: `df=pd.DataFrame({"Date":[date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,2),date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,2),date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,2),date(2019,10,1),date(2019,10,2)],
                "ShopID":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                "ProductID":[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2],
                "Quantity":[None,None,None,None,None,None,None,3]})`, some rows dissappear.

Comment: @william007 That's because `pivot_table` drops `nan` by defaults. You can either add `dropna=False` to `df.pivot_table(..., dropna=False)` or use `df.pivot()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1: using `pivot_table` with `join` (vectorized solution)

We can `pivot` your `quantity` values per `shopid, productid` to columns, and then join them back to your original dataframe. This should be way faster than your `forloops` since this is a vectorized approach:

```
piv = df.pivot_table(index=['ShopID', 'ProductID'], columns=['ShopID', 'ProductID'], values='Quantity')
piv2 = piv.ffill().bfill()
piv3 = piv2.mask(piv2.eq(piv))

final = df.set_index(['ShopID', 'ProductID']).join(piv3).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
   ShopID  ProductID         dt  Quantity  (1, 1)  (1, 2)  (2, 1)  (2, 2)
0       1          1 2019-10-01         3     NaN     4.0     5.0     6.0
1       1          1 2019-10-02         3     NaN     4.0     5.0     6.0
2       1          2 2019-10-01         4     3.0     NaN     5.0     6.0
3       1          2 2019-10-02         4     3.0     NaN     5.0     6.0
4       2          1 2019-10-01         5     3.0     4.0     NaN     6.0
5       2          1 2019-10-02         5     3.0     4.0     NaN     6.0
6       2          2 2019-10-01         6     3.0     4.0     5.0     NaN
7       2          2 2019-10-02         6     3.0     4.0     5.0     NaN
```

---

#### Method 2, using `GroupBy`, `mask`, where:

We can speed up your code by using [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) + [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) instead of two `for-loops`:

```
groups = df.groupby(['ShopID', 'ProductID'])

for grp, data in groups:
    m = df['ShopID'].eq(grp[0]) & df['ProductID'].eq(grp[1])
    values = df['Quantity'].where(m).ffill().bfill()
    df[f'Quantity_{grp[0]}_{grp[1]}'] = values.mask(m)
```

**Output**

```
          dt  ShopID  ProductID  Quantity  Quantity_1_1  Quantity_1_2  Quantity_2_1  Quantity_2_2
0 2019-10-01       1          1         3           NaN           4.0           5.0           6.0
1 2019-10-02       1          1         3           NaN           4.0           5.0           6.0
2 2019-10-01       1          2         4           3.0           NaN           5.0           6.0
3 2019-10-02       1          2         4           3.0           NaN           5.0           6.0
4 2019-10-01       2          1         5           3.0           4.0           NaN           6.0
5 2019-10-02       2          1         5           3.0           4.0           NaN           6.0
6 2019-10-01       2          2         6           3.0           4.0           5.0           NaN
7 2019-10-02       2          2         6           3.0           4.0           5.0           NaN
```

Comment: Some thing tells me you ignore the date of the records.

Comment: Try with different quantities on different dates.

Comment: actually the second one would be incorrect as well since you use `ffill` and `bfill` without grouping on Date?